# C# Datagridview performance suffers when hiding many rows

Tags: c#, performance, datagridview

I've made a DataGradView in C# which allows me to collapse and expand rows.
Looks like this:

[image]

At startup i want to collapse all customers with multiple entrys. Like the one shown in picture. Works well if the total number of `customers is < 10.000`
If total number of `customer is > 10.000` it takes a few minutes to go.

Code to collapse all customers:

```
   int number = 0;
        int oldnumber = 0;
        int parent = 0;

        foreach (CustomDataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            try
            {
                number = int.Parse(row.Cells[1].Value.ToString());

                if (number != oldnumber && int.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[row.Index + 1].Cells[1].Value.ToString()) == number)
                {
                    row.Is_expander = true;
                    parent = row.Index;

                }
                if (number == oldnumber)
                {
                    row.hide(parent);
                }
                oldnumber = number;
            }
            catch { }
        }
```

foreach row which has to collapse i call `row.hide(parent)`, which set the visibility to false and saves the parent index.

foreach parent row an icon will be drawn

Can you guess why it takes so long to hide all these rows?
Maybe after each hidden row screen draws again?
Maybe i am doing unnecessary or heavy-performance stuff in loop?
I have no idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `VirtualMode` with `DataGridView` in order to very efficiently update the grid.  See this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171622.aspx

If you are rendering > 10,000 virtual-mode is a must!

Comment: Just setting virtualmode = true did not shows any result.
btw: it also seems that it takes exponentially time to hide all rows.
5000 rows in 2 seconds and 20.000 rows in 2 minutes

Comment: Read the referenced article, virtual mode is more than just a boolean property. You have to handle the various events that are fired to populate the visible window of cells. I have created a grouped grid that can render 100,000 + rows using this approach.

Comment: which events exactly are fired when hiding a row? Do you hiding or removing rows? Ive found out that removing and adding is more efficent then hiding

Answer (score 5):

Hiding and showing rows on a datagridview is very slow for a reason only microsoft knows, I guess. However, copying the rows to an array, manipulating them in the array and copying them back to the grid is **very** fast. Here is some code:

```
DataGridViewRow[] theRows = new DataGridViewRow[Adgv.Rows.Count];
Adgv.Rows.CopyTo(theRows, 0);
Adgv.Rows.Clear();
for (int loop = 0; loop < theRows.Length; loop++) theRows[loop].Visible = false;
Adgv.Rows.AddRange(theRows);
```

This gets done in less than a second for 35000 rows. In my code I usually have an expression that defines whether the row is to be hidden or shown and it is with the expression that it gets executed in less than a second.
If I attempt to do that operation without copying it takes a few minutes. Go figure!

Comment: Of all that I have tried, this one worked for me (non-data tabled DatagridView) 

Thank you.

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me. Note that this will reset the selection however, so if you need to retain it you must store and restore that manually.

Answer (score 1):

Is that necessary to select all 10000 rows from the start. It is possible to display data in different pages starting from 1-9,10-19,20-19 etc. It will boost performance and also provide system of paging. Why can't you try to modify the query ?

Comment: It is necessary to select all 10000 rows from the start

Comment: then its better to do calculations inside sp/sql and returns the dataset and assign it to gridviews datasource

Answer (score 1):

If the autosize is set, there is a problem with the Grid. On every change of the visible - attribute, the complete grid is checked for the perfekt size.

Try out these:

```
Grid.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.None;

foreach (DataGridViewRow Row in Grid.Rows) 
{
   if (......) 
   {
     Row.Visible = false;
   }
}
Grid.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
```

Comment: You have to do this for each column if it should work

Answer (score 1):

In my case dataGridView was very slow when changing the `dataGrid1.Rows[z].Visible` property. The solution was to turn the AutoSize off temporarily:

```
for (int z = 0; z < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; z++)
{ // Disabled AutoSize Mode for all columns
  dataGridView1.Columns[iRow].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None;
}

for (int iRow = 0; iRow <= dataGridView1.RowCount; iRow++)
{ // Filtering dataGridView1
  bool bVisibleCondition = ...
  dataGridView1.Rows[iRealRow].Visible = bVisibleCondition;
}

for (int z = 0; z < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; z++)
{ // Enable AutoSize Mode for all columns
  dataGridView1.Columns[z].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
}
```