# Building a grid defining specific columns and rows from a stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a stored procedure that returns a few columns, I am only interested in building a gridview with the `ProjectID` values that are null. My code below returns all the rows of all the columns, it is just supposed to return where column = projectID. Can someone take a look at it. Thanks

```
DataRowCollection rowCollection = spDataTable.Rows;
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

foreach (DataColumn col in spDataTable.Columns)
{
                if (col.ColumnName == "ProjectID")
                {
                    dt.Columns.Add(col.ColumnName);
                    lb_Test.Items.Add(col.ColumnName);
                        foreach(DataRow ros in col.Table.Rows)
                        {
                            foreach (object oObj in ros.ItemArray)
                            {
                                if (oObj != null)
                                {
                                    if (col.ColumnName == "ProjectID")
                                    {
                                        lb_Test.Items.Add(oObj.ToString());
                                        dt.Rows.Add(oObj);
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    lb_Test.Items.Add("Null");
                                }
                            }   
                        }
                        grd_test.DataSource = dt;
                        grd_test.DataBind();
                }
                else
                {
                    lb_Test.Items.Add("Not valid Name");
                }
}
```

Comment: every row contains a column named "ProjectID"

Comment: @jpavlov filter the rows for null vs not null from your data layer not your UI layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding the question, seems like all you need is this...

```
DataRowCollection rowCollection = spDataTable.Rows; 
DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 

foreach(DataRow dr in spDataTable.Rows)
{
        object projectId = dr["ProjectID"];
        if (projectId == null)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
     }
```

This will populate the rowCollection with all the rows where the value in the ProjectID column is null.

Having said this, if you can, you may consider changing your stored procedure to only returns the rows you want.  This will save network traffic.

Also, a DataTable has built-in filtering capabilities...[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zk13kdh0(v=vs.71).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zk13kdh0%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).  Maybe this would be a better approach.

DataViews also have the capability to filter data.  Then you can bind your GridView to a DataView...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10893860/how-to-filter-gridview-from-textbox

There are several ways to filter DataTables that are built into .Net.  There is no need to roll your own.

Comment: I am not able to add to the rowCollection, with this

Comment: @jpavlov Sorry...I think it should be "dt.Rows.Add(dr)".  Having said that, please consider the alternatives.  It is better to use the built-in filtering capabilities rather then rolling your own.  Much more flexible.