# can not bind to datatable with no name error while filtering a gridview

Tags: c#, sql

I have a `datagridview` and 5 `ComboBoxes` and I am trying to filter the grid's rows with ComboBox's text values. The grid is filled with stored procedure depends on some conditions in `FormLoad` event. Should I fill it again in the `btn_filter` click event?

Anyway this exception is catched at code below: `cannot bind to datatable with no name.`

here is the code for `btn_filter`:

```
    private void btnFilter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String filterStr = "";

        if (cmbGrp.Text.Trim() != String.Empty)
            filterStr +=  "group ='" + cmbGrp.Text.Trim() + "' and";
        if(cmbMdl.Text.Trim() != String.Empty)
            filterStr += " model ='" + cmbMdl.Text.Trim() + "' and";
        if (cmbTrh.Text.Trim() != String.Empty)
            filterStr += " tarh ='" + cmbTrh.Text.Trim() + "' and";
        if (cmbSiz.Text.Trim() != String.Empty)
            filterStr += " size ='" + cmbSiz.Text.Trim() + "' and";
        if (cmbClr.Text.Trim() != String.Empty)
            filterStr += " color ='" + cmbClr.Text.Trim() + "'";            

        if (filterStr.LastIndexOf("and") == filterStr.Length - 3)
            filterStr = filterStr.Remove(filterStr.Length-3,3);


        DataView view = new DataView();
        if (condition1)
            view.Table = Production.usp1(txtProdCode.Text);
        else if (condition2)
            view.Table = Production.usp2();
        else
            return;
        view.RowFilter = filterStr;
        dgv.DataSource = view;    
    }
```

and here is the storedProcedure related functions (in `Production` class):

```
    public static DataTable usp2()
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp2");
        return callProc(cmd);
    }

    public static DataTable usp1(String prod_code)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp1");
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@prod_code", prod_code));
        return callProc(cmd);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try specify Name explicitly. use `DataTable.TableName="Name"` before you create your dataview.
You btnFilter_Click method should look like this:

```
 private void btnFilter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String filterStr = "";

        filterStr +=      "grp_name " + (cmbGrp.Text.Trim() == String.Empty ? " like '%'" : "='" + cmbGrp.Text.Trim()) + "'";
        filterStr += " and mdl_name " + (cmbMdl.Text.Trim() == String.Empty ? " like '%'" : "='" + cmbMdl.Text.Trim()) + "'";
        filterStr += " and trh_name " + (cmbTrh.Text.Trim() == String.Empty ? " like '%'" : "='" + cmbTrh.Text.Trim()) + "'";
        filterStr += " and siz_name " + (cmbSiz.Text.Trim() == String.Empty ? " like '%'" : "='" + cmbSiz.Text.Trim()) + "'";
        filterStr += " and clr_name " + (cmbClr.Text.Trim() == String.Empty ? " like '%'" : "='" + cmbClr.Text.Trim()) + "'";

        DataView view = new DataView();

        if (condition1)
           {
            var dt = Production.usp1(txtProdCode.Text);
            dt.TableName="usp1";
            view.Table = dt;
            }
        else if (condition2)
            {
            var dt = Production.usp2();
            dt.TableName="usp2";
            view.Table = dt;
            }
        else
            return;
        view.RowFilter = filterStr;
        dgv.DataSource = view;    
    }
```

To not reload grid with values from DB again you can cast your existing datasource to DataView like this:

```
(dataGridViewFields.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter
```

Read more in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843537/filtering-datagridview-without-changing-datasource)

Comment: is there a way for not filling the grid again, before filter? i am using this cast: `DataTable dt = (DataTable)dgv.DataSource;`

Comment: @rene, yes, you can do it the way you're showing in this comment. you can cast your datasource to dataview, make filtering and call DataBind again. read more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843537/filtering-datagridview-without-changing-datasource

Answer (score 0):

Thanks user1792936, the way you implemented is correct but There is a more simple way: [according to this link and answer of Brad Bruce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843537/filtering-datagridview-without-changing-datasource)

I don't need to fill the grid again:

```
(dgv.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = filterStr;
```