# DataView from strongly typed DataSet

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, dataview, strongly-typed-dataset

We have a strongly typed DataSet created by using the DataSet designer in Visual Studio.

Can you show us the needed coding to create a DataView from this DataSet?

This will be used in an ASP.Net VB.Net GridViewSummary.Sorting handler in a code-behind file.

Here is the coding we are trying but need help with it:

```
Protected Sub GridViewSummary_Sorting(sender As Object, e As GridViewSortEventArgs) Handles GridViewSummary.Sorting

    ViewState("sortExpr") = e.SortExpression
    GridViewSummary.DataSource = bindgrid()
    GridViewSummary.DataBind()
End Sub

Private Function bindgrid() As DataView

    Dim dv As DataView = New DataView
    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable

    dt.TableName = "Classes"
    dv.Table = dt

    If ViewState("sortExpr") IsNot Nothing Then
        dv.Sort = DirectCast(ViewState("sortExpr"), String)
    End If

    Return dv

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Dataview can be accessed like this:  `myDataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView` .
If you want to sort GridView directly, you can convert GridView to dataview and apply sort.

```
(dataGridViewFields.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.Sort = ....
```

I've answered a similar question here:  [can not bind to datatable with no name error while filtering a gridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13351980/can-not-bind-to-datatable-with-no-name-error-while-filtering-a-gridview/13352049#13352049)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you show where to place your coding based on what we are trying to do in the sample coding I added?

Comment: @Emad-ud-deen, I don't really understand what your problem is with the code. Can you explain a little better where you have a problem.

Comment: I found some coding online to implement sorting when the user clicks on the header of an ASP.Net GridView. The coding we are trying to implement is to alter the strongly typed DataSet so the data in the DataView is sorted based on the value in ViewState("sortExpr"). I realize we can create several queries in the DataSet designer but wanted to try and do all of that using code instead if that can be done. At present, we don't know how to implement the correct coding for Function bindgrid().

Comment: Almost there. I changed the bindgrid() function based on some of the coding in your other posting but get an error that the column names are not found then the user views the web form. I updated my posting to show the new changes. "Classes" is the name of the table we created in the DataSet designer. Can you also give more details on how to change the GridView directly in code?