# Does filtering a DataView filter the DataSource?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, dataview

If I apply a filter to a `DataView`, does it filter the `DataSource` as well. For example, if I have 7 rows in my `DataSource` and I filter it so I see 3 rows in a `GridView`, does the `DataView.DataSource` now have 3 rows or does it still keep the original 7?

Comment: Why don't you test it yourself? (no, it does not)

Comment: @TimSchmelter - I did test it, but I just wanted to confirm it.  I verified that it does not, but I wasn't confident enough in my test, so someone with more experience would be able to confirm it.

Comment: No, it does not. [The discussion of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843537/filtering-datagridview-without-changing-datasource) has more information.