# Filter rows in my DataGridView?

Tags: c#, binding, datagridview, datatable, dataset

This is not easy, as far as I know, I can only filter rows in my DataGridView when it's DataSource is assigned for a DataTable (use DefaultView.RowFilter) or a BindingSource (use Filter). But my DataGridView DataSource is like this:

```
myDataGridView.DataSource = myDataSet;
myDataGridView.DataMember = "myTableName";
//filtering rows using myDataSet.Tables["myTableName"].RowFilter = "..." doesn't work.
```

myDataSet is alreadly bound to some controls on my form and I don't want to rebind it when myDataGridView's DataSource changes.

I don't want to set my DataGridView's DataSource like this:

```
myDataGridView.DataSource = myDataTable;
//then use myDataTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = "...";
//or
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource(myDataSet, "myTableName");
myDataGridView.DataSource = bs;
//then use bs.Filter = "..."
```

I just want my DataGridView datasource as in the first code, how can I filter rows for it in that context? Please be sure it works and notice about what I mentioned here.

Your help would be highly appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: Well this actually turned me off *Please be sure it works ...*

Comment: Really? if you're not sure it works, so post it as a comment, just a suggestion is OK, thanks!

Comment: @V4Vendetta plus, if your comment is helpful, I'll notify you about that and then I'll would like you to post the official answer. I mean I just need a suggestion, the test is for me and you'll know the result after I test. Thanks!

Comment: Never mind that it isn't the right way to use BindingSource, why you don't want to use BindingSource?

Answer (score 1):

Try `myDataSet.Tables["myTableName"].DefaultView.RowFilter = "..."`

if that doesn't float your boat then this from [another SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843537/filtering-datagridview-without-changing-datasource).

`(dataGridViewFields.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Field = '{0}'", textBoxFilter.Text);`