# Displaying specific rows from a data table in a Windows Forms Application

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I'm new to this but I'm using C# and am trying to make a Windows forms application where I can display only specific rows from a data table. I'm using a disconnected application (loading the SQL database into a dataset) and I am trying to show only rows where the value of a specific column is equal to a number that is chosen by the user.

What is the best way to display this information?
How do I only show those specific rows?

Comment: Your SQL Datasource must have some way to pass a parameter which will be used in the query, so only the filtered results will be retrieved. I'd recommend using an Object Based datasource instead of SQL though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create [BindingSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.aspx)
, bind to your DataTable and use Filter property

Comment: Just to expand on the comment by @ghost .  Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843537/filtering-datagridview-without-changing-datasource/10049875#10049875

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DataTable` `Select` method.

[DataTable.Select Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/det4aw50.aspx)

> Gets an array of all DataRow objects that match the filter criteria.

[DataTable.Select Method (String, String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/way3dy9w.aspx)

> Gets an array of all DataRow objects that match the filter criteria,
>   in the specified sort order.

[DataTable.Select Method (String, String, DataViewRowState)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5c0xc84.aspx)

> Gets an array of all DataRow objects that match the filter in the
>   order of the sort that match the specified state.

Or you can create a `DataView` ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy5b8exc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

Examples of using those method you can find under the links that I gave you above.

Binding to ListBox:

*DataTable.Select:*

```
DataTable myTable = new DataTable();
myTable.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
myTable.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));

DataRow myNewRow = null;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    myNewRow = myTable.NewRow();

    myNewRow["Id"] = i;
    myNewRow["Name"] = "Name " + i.ToString();

    myTable.Rows.Add(myNewRow);
}

DataRow[] Array = myTable.Select("Id > 5");

DataTable newTable = myTable.Clone();

foreach (var item in Array)
{
    newTable.ImportRow(item);
}

listBox1.DataSource = newTable;
listBox1.ValueMember = "Id";
listBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

*DataView:*

```
   DataView custDV = new DataView(myTable, 
    "Id > 5", 
    "Name", 
    DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);

listBox1.DataSource = custDV;
listBox1.ValueMember = "Id";
listBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

Comment: Can I then display the arrays in a listbox?

Comment: @user2579701 Yes, you can. Check my answer again :)