# How to filter DataGridView by Substring?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

I have my `DataGridView` with `DataSource` . I need to filter all rows by string value.

E.g.

In `DataGridView` are 3 rows:

```
Customer1.Text     SomeValue
Customer1.State    SomeState
Customer1.Name     SomeName
```

I need by applying filter ".Text" my `DataGridView` contains only one row:

```
Customer1.Text     SomeValue
```

I tried with code:

```
var records = new BindingList<CRecord>
        {
           new CRecord("Customer1.Text", "SomeValue"),
           new CRecord("Customer1.State", "SomeState"),
           new CRecord("Customer1.Name", "SomeName"),
         };

var recordsBindingSource = new BindingSource();
var records = new BindingList<CRecord> {

recordsBindingSource.DataSource = records;
dgvCustomers.DataSource = recordsBindingSource;

var bindingList = (BindingSource)currentDgv.DataSource;
bindingList.Filter = "ElementName like '%.Text%'";
```

But nothing happens. How can I do my filtering?

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust your sql query and rebind the grid with it.

Comment: I don't perform any SQL queries. All my data displayed at code.

Comment: Check this out, it might help you some http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843537/filtering-datagridview-without-changing-datasource

Answer (score 0):

A `BindingSource` also has a property called `Filter` used to filter rows data, you can just use it without involving any BindingList:

```
recordsBindingSource.Filter = "ElementName like '%.Text%'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Confirm if the `BindingSource` has the property `SupportsFiltering` enabled.If not,you can't filter by `BindingSource` because the fields are marked has ReadOnly.