# Filtering sql data with multiple filter vb.net (winform)

Tags: sql, vb.net, winforms

I want to filtering data from SQL to my datagrid.

I have :

1 table (tableX)

3 Columns

```
 Col1    Col2      Col3
1/x/10    BJB    1/20/20
1/y/10    BJB    1/20/30
1/x/10    BJB    1/20/30
1/y/10    BJB    1/20/20
```

2 datagrid (dg1, dg2)

i want insert :

dg1 with col1 "1/x/10" and col3 "10/20/20"

dg2 with col1 "1/y/10 and col3 "10/20/20

i can filter with only one Col3

```
"SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3  FROM Tablex WHERE Col3='10/20/20'"
```

how to filter col1 witch contain "x" or "y" and col3?

==========================================================================

O YEAH.. thanks for the answer.

this for dg1

```
("SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3  FROM TableX WHERE Col1 like ('%/X/%') AND Col3='10/20/20'")
```

and this for dg2, the different is just X and Y..lol

```
("SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3  FROM TableX WHERE Col1 like ('%/Y/%') AND Col3='10/20/20'")
```

Comment: If I am reading your question correctly this SO post will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843537/filtering-datagridview-without-changing-datasource

Comment: Are you saying you want to make one call to the database that will fill both datagrids?

Comment: no, iam not.. 1 command for 1 datagrid.

Comment: Then `SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3  FROM Tablex WHERE Col3='10/20/20' AND Col1 = '1/x/10'` for one and `SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3  FROM Tablex WHERE Col3='10/20/20' AND Col1 = '1/y/10'` for the other.

Comment: @Fred your code is working but.. col1 is not always "1/x/10" and "1/y/10.. the x and y is static, but 1 and 10 always change.. sory my bad question...

Comment: Ok then you will need to use the Like command as @slavoo suggested. Split it into two commands  `SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3 FROM Tablex 
WHERE Col3='10/20/20' AND COL1 like '%/x/%'` and `SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3 FROM Tablex WHERE Col3='10/20/20' AND COL1 like '%/y/%'`  If you want to include all rows where Col1 has a 'x' or 'y' then the like is 'like '%x%'` and 'like '%y%'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3  
FROM Tablex 
WHERE Col3='10/20/20'
AND (COL1 like '%/x/%' or COL1 like '%/y/%')
```

Comment: ihave error ERROR [42000] [MySQL][ODBC 5.2(w) Driver][mysqld-5.5.25a]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%'X'%)' at line 1.

Comment: Why use Like?  `Where (COL1 = '1/x/10'  or COL1 like '1/y/10')` is more effcient but based on the dataset above this query is the same as `SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3  
FROM Tablex`

Comment: @Fred Are you sure that everytime there will be only these strings ('1/x/10', '1/y/10')? OP ask `how to filter col1 witch contain "x" or "y"` and I think this is only example data.

Comment: Apologies, the question was obviously clearer to you than me! :)  ps I didn't downvote you.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3  
FROM Tablex 
WHERE COL1 IN ('1/x/10', '1/y/10')
AND Col3 = '10/20/20
```

Or you can make the `COL1` filter more ambiguous.

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3  
FROM Tablex 
WHERE COL1 IN ('%/x/%', '%/y/%')
AND Col3 = '10/20/20
```

Comment: SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3  FROM Tablex WHERE COL1 IN ('x', 'y') AND Col3 = '10/20/20' its return nothing..

Comment: Have a look now, updated the answer, i was originally just using x and y as placeholders, i didn't realise you have them in your data.