# How do I implement multi-input XOR with DataView.RowFilter?

Tags: c#, dataview

I understand that 2-input XOR can be done by using their NAND and NOR equivalents but that approach is quickly becomes convoluted when the number of possibles inputs are unknown. Is there a simpler way?

An example would be having 3 conditions, each applying to a different column of the DataView. How would I filter the DataView for rows where only an odd number of those conditions are true?

Comment: @GrantWinney Well, since XOR is associative and I do not know number of input conditions I am given, I tried building the expression one variable at a time.

For the 3 condition example, A XOR B was written (A AND (NOT B)) OR ((NOT A) OR B), then (A XOR B) XOR C was written as ((A XOR B) AND (NOT C)) OR ((NOT (A XOR B)) OR C) (I used (A XOR B) instead of the full expression to shorten the example).

Comment: @AxelKemper I double checked the the documentation for the DataView.RowFilter property and there are no "!=" operators. It seems the only boolean operators allowed are AND OR and NOT. Guess I will just have to translate XORs into those boolean operators.

Comment: @AxelKemper Those operators are for building a condition aka "Name <> 'Tim'". I am trying to string such conditions together in an XOR-like fashion.

Comment: @AxelKemper You will still run into this problem because DataColumn.Expression is actually the same datatype as DataView.RowFilter and subject to the same restrictions.

Comment: @AxelKemper Interesting, that is actually better than what I have now (and honestly the best solution considering the restrictions). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following `C#` demo code shows how to implement a three-input `Xor` by using the built-in *if-then-else* `IIF()` function:

```
private string xorViaIIF(string a, string b, string c)
{
    return string.Format("IIF(IIF({0}, not ({1}), {1}), not ({2}), {2})", a, b, c);
}

private void filterDemo()
{
    //  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843537/filtering-datagridview-without-changing-datasource

    DataView dv = (this.dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView;

    if (dv.RowFilter == "")
    {
        dv.RowFilter = xorViaIIF("[A] = 'A1'", "[B] = 'B2'", "[C] = 'C3'");
    }
    else
    {
        dv.RowFilter = "";
    }
}
```

The resulting filter expression for this example does not exactly look simple:

```
IIF(IIF([A] = 'A1', not ([B] = 'B2'), [B] = 'B2'), not ([C] = 'C3'), [C] = 'C3')
```