# Filter Criteria % like % following Code

Tags: c#, datagridview

i use this code for focus row which match text in search text box.now how can i use  % like % criteria for this code

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in GdvDetails.Rows)
{
      var cellValue = row.Cells["Bunch Component"].Value;
      if (cellValue != null && cellValue.ToString() == txtSearch.Text)
      {
          GdvDetails.Rows[row.Index].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
      }
      else
      {
          GdvDetails.Rows[row.Index].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Empty;
      }
}
```

Comment: You want to filter of _what_? The `row.Cells["Bunch Component"]`? Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843537/filtering-datagridview-without-changing-datasource

Comment: i think that it is going about `cellValue.ToString().Contains(txtSearch.Text.Trim('%') /* not sure what input is, for safety */)` instead of `cellValue.ToString() == txtSearch.Text`

Comment: You can use `BindingSouce.Filter`. It supports wildcards

Comment: want to search %txtsearch.text% present in cell & if present then Focus it.e.g. user type LH in txtsearch then find rows that are contain LH in Cell

Comment: i use checkbox column in datagridview if i use binding source it will reset all values of checkbox to unchecked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
 foreach (DataGridViewRow row in GdvDetails.Rows)
{
  var cellValue = row.Cells["Bunch Component"].Value;
  if (cellValue != null)
 { 
  if ( cellValue.ToString().Contains(txtSearch.Text))
  {
      GdvDetails.Rows[row.Index].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
  }
  else
  {
      GdvDetails.Rows[row.Index].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Empty;
  }
}
}
```