# How can i filter gridview depend on text changed in text box

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, ado.net

I want to filter the `GridView` depend on the `TextBox` in form down .. I want when I write for example `ec` it shows all rows with company name include `ec` then if I change the string in the `TextBox` the data changes also in the `GridView`.

Comment: You can use the TextChanged event on a TextBox for this. Have you tried anything already?

Comment: Ok .. But how can i use textchanged event .. I tried more cods but it was not working

Comment: __Do not__ call a `DataGridView`a `GridView`!! This is wrong and confusing and and bound to get wrong answers wasting everybody's time.. Always call things by their __right__ name! Yes, it takes __four__ letters more to type, but when asking for help here is __not__ the time to be so lazy..! -

Comment: possible duplicate of [Filtering DataGridView without changing datasource](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843537/filtering-datagridview-without-changing-datasource)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DoubleClick on your `TextBox` and write code here:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string sql = "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Name LIKE @Name";
    using (SqlCommand cmd= new SqlCommand(sql, cn))
    {
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", "%" + textBox1.Text + "%");
      //rest of the code
      //dataGridView.DataSource = your DataSource;
    }
}
```

**Edit**: To avoid pulling data from the db on each keystroke, Try this in `textBox1_TextChanged` Event:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();//Populate ds from a SqlDataAdapter

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataView dv = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
    dv.RowFilter = string.Format("name LIKE '%{0}%'", textBox1.Text);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dv;
}
```

Comment: I doubt that pulling data from the db on each keystroke is a good idea. Using a BindingSource is a lot better that all those sql calls..!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the row filter property on the datagrid?

```
(dataGridViewFields.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Field = '{0}'", textBoxFilter.Text);
```

See Brad Bruce's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843537/filtering-datagridview-without-changing-datasource) for an example.

Comment: Did you change the name of the "Field" to the column you want to search?