# Design advise needed on editing and filtering a datagridview

Tags: winforms, datagridview, datatable

I have a design question that involves DataGridView and DataTable, bound by a BindingSource in a WinForms application. The DataTable is populated by a sql server table.

The user can add new rows in the DataGrid, delete rows and edit rows.
When he is done he clicks on a button which will start a loop through the DataTable which will edit some tables, insert into some table and delete from some tables depending on what he did in the DataGridView.

This is all no problem and it works fine. 
But now I have to let the user also filter the data, so the DataGridView will show more or less records.

The problem here is that when the user adds a new row, deletes a few rows, changes a few rows, and than applies a filter that could filter out one or more of these records, the loop in the button should still see these records to process them.

What is the best design for handling this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filter shouldn't affect the loop. For example, in the following code I set the `DataGridView.DataSource` from a `DataTable` that has an applied filter and loop through the table, printing values:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Quantity", typeof(int));

dt.Rows.Add("Foo", 1);
dt.Rows.Add("Bar", 2);
dt.Rows.Add("Baz", 3);

string filterField = "Name";
string filterText = "B";
dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("[{0}] LIKE '%{1}%'", filterField, filterText);

this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", row.ItemArray[0]);
}
```

With the filter, the `DataGridView` displays only select entries. But looping through the `DataTable` rows still prints every entry.

[image: Filtered DataTable Output and DGV]

Therefore, when handling binding such as a `BindingSource`, after the `DataGridView` is already sourced, you might change your filter like so to have a dynamic searching option:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BindingSource bs = this.dataGridView1.DataSource as BindingSource;
    DataTable dt = bs.DataSource as DataTable;
    dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("[{0}] LIKE '{1}%'", "Name", this.textBox1.Text);
}
```

Comment: DefaultView.RowFilter looks promising, will try that first thing tomorrow. My DataTable is bound to the DataGrid using a BindingSource, so I guess that I just need to set this property and the BindingSource will take care that the DataGridView shows the filtered resultset ?

Comment: @GuidoG Correct. Setting the filter on the `DataTable`, then setting `bindingSource.DataSource = dataTable;` and `dataGridView.DataSource = bindingSource;` will still correctly display a filtered list in the dgv, while iterating through that `DataTable` will display an unfiltered list.

Answer (score 1):

I just found an even better way to filter the `DataGridView`from a question (yes it was a question) posted by [mj82](https://stackoverflow.com/users/732542/mj82):

[Filtering DataGridView without changing datasource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843537/filtering-datagridview-without-changing-datasource?rq=1)

This was the most helpful part of the question.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
    dt.Columns.Add("country", typeof(string));

    dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, "Belgium" });
    dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, "France" });
    dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 3, "Germany" });
    dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 4, "Spain" });
    dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 5, "Swiss" });
    dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 6, "United Kingdom" });

    bs.DataSource = dt;
    dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
}

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("DataSource type BEFORE = " + dataGridView1.DataSource.GetType().ToString());

    bs.Filter = string.Format("country LIKE '%{0}%'", textBox1.Text);

    MessageBox.Show("DataSource type AFTER = " + dataGridView1.DataSource.GetType().ToString());
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @KhanImranAli Yes you are right, I edited the answer so it includes the part from this link that helped me.