# Filtering my Datagridview for a Textbox text

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview, filter

I'm actually trying to filter my Datagridview for a text from my Textbox of a specific column. The thing is, I picked Code from another thread here, but it keeps telling me that the Datasource of my Datagridview is 'Null'

My Datagridview Code

```
private void Icon_Picker_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] first = {"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17"};

    dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
    dataGridView1.Refresh();
    //image directory
    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\Daniel\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\images");

    //getting all files from the Directory
    foreach(FileInfo file in dir.GetFiles())
    {

        try
        {
            this.img16x16.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(file.FullName));
            this.img32x32.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(file.FullName));


            for (int j = 0; j < img16x16.Images.Count; j++)
            {
                var row = new DataGridViewRow();

                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
                dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells[0].Value = first[j];

                //Resizing icons to 16x16 icons
                img16x16.ImageSize = new Size(16, 16);

                //adding icons to the datagridview
                dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells[1].Value = img16x16.Images[j];

                //Resizing icons to 32x32 icons
                img32x32.ImageSize = new Size(32, 32);

                //adding icons to the datagridview
                dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells[2].Value = img32x32.Images[j];


            }

        }catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is not an image file");
        }
    }
```

My TextChanged Function

```
 private void txtFilter_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

         (dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Field = '{0}'", txtFilter.Text);
    }
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: where do you initially bind the datagridview..? use the debugger and step through the code.. tell us the exact line that you notice the datagridview is null.. also where are you binding it initially where do you assign the DataSource..? also your filter do shouldn't it be `Like` instead of `=`

Comment: `dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);` you are adding rows directly to the DGV and are not using a DataSource, so any attempt to use DS related ops such as a DataView or filter wont work...you could manually iterate rows and set `.Visible` for the non matching ones to false.

Comment: You could either hide the `DataGridView` rows as suggested by Plutonix, or you change the way you set the grid up. Instead of creating columns and rows in the DGV, create them in a `DataTable`. Then set that as your source and your filtering code above should work. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31970528/3773066) I give an example of setting the `DataTable` up, and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31818204/3773066) I give different filtering options like MethodMan mentioned.

Comment: Alright, Thank you guys. I just changed the way i fill my datagridview like OhBeWise did in his example. Thank you so much :)