# How to make a filtrer using a textbox and datagridview? VB.NET 2010 and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datagridview

I'm working with SQL Server 2008 and Visual Basic 2010 and I have my data source and I designed a form using it, the function that I need to make is a filter, when I introduce something and the textbox I would like to see the results in my datagridview.

I tried by this way:

```
Private Sub IDConsultorTextBox_PreviewKeyDown(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.PreviewKeyDownEventArgs) Handles IDConsultorTextBox.PreviewKeyDown
        Me.DatosConsultorTableAdapter.FillByIDConsultor(Me.SIGEO.DatosConsultor, "%" & IDConsultorTextBox.Text & "%")
 End Sub
```

When I run the program nothing happens

Comment: Use profiler to see what command is being sent to SQL from your .net app.

Comment: If your `DataSource` is a `DataTable`, just set the `RowFilter` as I've shown in answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31970528/3773066) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31818204/3773066). If the `DataSource` is a `BindingSource`, similarly set the `Filter` as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31981268/3773066). These examples are in C#, but [converting](http://converter.telerik.com/) them to vb.net should be trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Why not apply a filter your datasource?