# How to search/filter the datagridview in textchanged event

Tags: c#, winforms, search, datagridview, filter

I would like to filter my `DataGridView` items using textbox that instantly changes the results after typing a letter (in `TextChanged` event).
The problem is that I only found a way to do this with SQL connection and select queries.

The list that is the `DataSource` for `DataGridView`:

```
public static List<string> listaOsob = new List<string>();
static Osoba nr1 = new Osoba(0, "n0", "f0", 1);
static Osoba nr2 = new Osoba(1, "n1", "f1", 1);
static Osoba nr3 = new Osoba(2, "n2", "f2", 1);
```

The `DataSource` for my `DataGridView` is a list, I'm adding it like this:

```
dataGridViewOsob.DataSource = listaOsob;
```

Any help and code samples would be very appreciated.

Comment: Try lambdas: `dataGridViewOsob.DataSource = listaOsob.Where(o => o.Field2.StartsWith(textBox1.Text));` You can use whatever string comparison you like: `StartsWith`, `Contains`, `Equals`, et. al. Use this method in the `TextBox.TextChanged` event handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My class declaration for your Osoba class

```
public class Osoba
{
    public int id {get;set;}
    public string name1 {get;set;}
    public string name2 {get;set;}
    public int num {get;set;}

    public Osoba(int _id, string _name1, string _name2, int _num)
    {
        this.id = _id;
        this.name1 = _name1;
        this.name2 = _name2;
        this.num = _num;
    }
 }
```

static declare list (based from your code)

```
public static List<Osoba> listOsob = new List<Osoba>()
{   new Osoba(0, "n0", "f0", 1)
    , new Osoba(1, "n1", "f1", 1)
    , new Osoba(2, "n2", "f2", 1)
};
```

on my form load

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = listOsob;
```

and on my text change

```
List<Osoba> newList = new List<Osoba>();
string search = textBox1.Text;

foreach (Osoba item in listOsob)
{
   var props = item.GetType().GetProperties();
   foreach (var prop in props)
   {
      if (Convert.ToString(prop.GetValue(item, null)).Contains(search))
      {
          newList.Add(item);
          break;
      }
   }
}
dataGridView1.DataSource = search == "" ? listOsob : newList;
```

hopefully this helps.

EDIT : If you want to specify your filters, you may edit the filter like this.

```
foreach (var prop in props)
   {
      if (
            (prop.Name == "name1") 
            || (prop.Name == "name2"))
      {
         if (Convert.ToString(prop.GetValue(item, null)).Contains(search))
         {
             newList.Add(item);
             break;
         }
      }
   }
```

EDIT : My apologies if your filter is kind of hard to derive, and with that specification I suggest to code your filter like below. Replace this

```
foreach (var prop in props)
   {
      if (
            (prop.Name == "name1") 
            || (prop.Name == "name2"))
      {
         if (Convert.ToString(prop.GetValue(item, null)).Contains(search))
         {
             newList.Add(item);
             break;
         }
      }
   }
```

with this

```
foreach (Osoba item in listOsob)
    {
       if (
            item.name1.Contains(search) 
         && item.name2.Contains(search) 
       )
       {
          newList.Add(item);
       }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. That solved the problem.
Is there any way that it could filter only by name1 and name2?

Comment: i've made an edit specifying property names for filter, hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! That worked as well. I would like to ask you one last thing: is there a way to filter the grid by name1 and name2 and not name1 or name2?

Comment: i've made an edit, hopefully this still helps. thanks

Comment: Thank you. That was a big help for me.

Answer (score 0):

Why did you declared nr1,nr2,nr3 as static?

You can use your class fields as source for you DataGridView. 
Based on your question it could be like:

```
public class Osoba
{
    [DisplayName("Id")]
    public int Field1{ get;set; }

    [DisplayName("Name")]
    public string Field2{ get;set; }

    [DisplayName("Name2")]
    public string Field3{ get;set; }

    [DisplayName("Id2")]
    public int Field4{ get;set; }
}
```

Where **DisplayName** annotation will be the column name.

And also you can mark field with annotation: **[Browsable(false)]** if you don't want the field has to be displayed in table structure

Then you can initialize your data collection like:

```
public static List<Osoba> listaOsob = new List<Osoba>
{
    new Osoba(0, "n0", "f0", 1),
    new Osoba(1, "n1", "f1", 1),
    new Osoba(2, "n2", "f2", 1)
};
```

and finally set your datagridView dataSource:

```
dataGridViewOsob.DataSource = listaOsob;
```

That should work.

Updating DataGridRow contents on textChanged event with various DataSource types is discussed [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843537/filtering-datagridview-without-changing-datasource)

Comment: This one doesn't really help me. I'm not able to add my class objects to the DataTable object.

Comment: I didn't understand that you have a problem with listaOsob initialization from your question description. I updated my answer.