# Filter contents of DataGridView without reloading data

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a MysqlTable adapter, and a Dataset being used like this:

```
 string sql = "SELECT firstName,lastName,phoneNumber FROM customers";
            daCustomers = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
            MySqlCommandBuilder cb = new MySqlCommandBuilder(daCustomers);

            dsCustomers = new DataSet();
            daCustomers.Fill(dsCustomers, "customers");
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dsCustomers;
            dataGridView1.DataMember = "customers";
```

Is there a way to filter what is shown in the dataGridView without reloading the data?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843537/filtering-datagridview-without-changing-datasource

Comment: I read this solution beforehand. It doesn't seem to work, I assumed because it was a MySqlTableAdapter. If I call (dataGridViewFields.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter, I get a property undefined error.

Comment: @PatrickSchomurg you need to associate the `dataGrid1Datasource` with the table just get rid of the Memeber line and do `dataGridView1.DataSource = dsCustomers.Tables[0]` then do `dataGridView1.DataBind()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are several ways you can do this.. for example create a Method that returns a DataSet

```
  public DataSet GetCustomers()
  {
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(
      "SELECT firstName,lastName,phoneNumber FROM customers", conn);

    DataSet custDS = new DataSet();
    adapter.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey;
    adapter.Fill(custDS, "Customers");

    return custDS;
  }
```

if you return the DataTable

```
public DataTable GetCustomers()
{
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(
      "SELECT firstName,lastName,phoneNumber FROM customers", conn);

    DataSet custDS = new DataSet();
    adapter.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey;
    adapter.Fill(custDS, "Customers");

    return custDS.Tables[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind a `DataView` instead of a `DataTable` and set a filter string (property `.RowFilter`) there.