# Search DataGridView using search query and like operator

Tags: c#

I want to search name in `DataGridView` using search query and `like` operator.

```
 public static DataSet SearchItems(string key)
    {
        string cmd = @"SELECT lt.ledgerId,la.ledgerName FROM ledgertranscationinfo lt  
                                JOIN ledgeraccreation la ON lt.ledgerId = la.ledgerId;                            
                                WHERE la.ledgerName LIKE CONCAT('"
                                + key.Trim() + "','%') ;";
        DataSet ds = MySQL_Helper.GetDataSet(CommandType.Text, cmd, "LedgerAcCreation");
        return ds;
    }
```

It show an error while searching text. Please give me proper solution for Text Search.

Comment: *It show an error while searching text* What error does it show you? Can you post it here

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/10049875/2130976