# How add filter to datagridview

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, csv, datagridview

I am trying to load a csv file to datagridview
and now i want to add filtering to the datagridview

How to do?
Here's how I read and load csv file

```
openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
openFileDialog1.Title = "Open CSV Files";
openFileDialog1.CheckFileExists = true;
openFileDialog1.CheckPathExists = true;
openFileDialog1.DefaultExt = "CSV";
openFileDialog1.Filter = "CSV files (*.csv)|*.csv|All files(*.*)|*.*";
openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;
openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
try
{
    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string csvPath = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        string rowValue;
        // int rowValue = int.Parse(??);
        string[] cellValue;
        dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
        //dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(csvPath))
        {
            System.IO.StreamReader fileReader = new StreamReader(csvPath);
            rowValue = fileReader.ReadLine();
            cellValue = rowValue.Split(',');



            for (int i = 0; i <= cellValue.Count() - 1; i++)
            {
                DataGridViewTextBoxColumn column = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
                column.Name = cellValue[i];    //column name , value
                column.HeaderText = cellValue[i];
                dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column);
                // dataGridView1.Columns[].CellType = typeof(Int64);
                //Conver.ToString
                dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter; // Korean? 칼럼 헤더 가운데 정렬
             //   dataGridView1.RowHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
               // dataGridView1.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "field name";
            }
            while (fileReader.Peek() != -1)
            {
                rowValue = fileReader.ReadLine();
                cellValue = rowValue.Split(',');
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(cellValue);
            }
            fileReader.Dispose();
            fileReader.Close();`
```

Comment: Instead of adding rows directly to `DataGridView` add them to a `DataTable` and then set that table as `DataSource` of your `DataGridView`, then use that `table.DefaultView.RowFilter` to filter the `DataGridView`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843537/filtering-datagridview-without-changing-datasource does this helps?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of adding rows directly to [`DataGridView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/datagridview-control-windows-forms?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) add them to a [`DataTable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataset-datatable-dataview/datatables?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) and then set that table as `DataSource` of your `DataGridView`, then use that `table.DefaultView.RowFilter` to filter the `DataGridView`.

You can simply change your code using below examples.

**Create a DataTable:**

```
var table = new DataTable();
```

**Add Column to DataTable:**

```
table.Columns.Add("column name");
```

**Add Row to DataTable:**

To add a row using a range for example a `string[]`:

```
table.Rows.Add(range);
```

**Set the table as `DataSource` of the `DataGridview`**

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
```

**Filter using DataTable:**

To filter using the data table, for example to show only rows where `FirstName` is `John`:

```
((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource).DefaultView.RowFilter = "FirstName = 'John'";
```

**Learn more:**

- [Creating a DataTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataset-datatable-dataview/creating-a-datatable?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)
- [Adding Columns to a DataTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataset-datatable-dataview/adding-columns-to-a-datatable?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)
- [Adding Data to a DataTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataset-datatable-dataview/adding-data-to-a-datatable?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)
- [DataView.RowFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataview.rowfilter?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) and [Filter Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: emm....Is that mean...first csv files adds to Datatable...and then add DataGridview?

Comment: First add columns and rows to `DataTable` then set the data table as `DataSource` of grid. This is using data binding to show data in grid.

Comment: I want to use button_click...and text_box....for example.. i want to see certain Rows_group...so, write row's name in text_box...and then button click   how to..?

Comment: I suppose you have a `FirstName` column, you can have e `firstNameTextBox` and in `button1_Click`, to show rows that have `FirstName` equals to what you typed, use this as filter expression: `string.Format("FirstName = '{0}'", firstNameTextBox.Text)`

Comment: to show rows that their`FirstName` contains (like) to what you typed, use this as filter expression: `string.Format("FirstName LIKE '%{0}&'", firstNameTextBox.Text)`

Comment: I've looked at many solutions for filtering DataGridView's this morning, and this is by far the simplest and cleanest! Thanks.