# Displaying original rowindex after filter in datagridview

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

Just want to ask on how to get the original row index of selected row in `DataGridView` after filter.

I have `DataGridView` with 2 columns :name and age. And I have a `TextBox` that serves as filter. Let's say I have 8 records and upon filtering it goes to only 4 records and upon clicking the last record, I get row index of 4, while I need to get the original index of this row and display it on `MessageBox`. How will I do it?
Thank you.

Comment: Is data bound or you add it manually?

Comment: Why do you even need index of it?

Comment: It is data bound,i need to display the current record selected. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Original row index means the index of the `DataRow` in the `DataTable` which can be found by `DataTable.Rows.IndexOf(row)`. So to find the original index of the row you can use the following code:

```
var r = ((DataRowView)BindingContext[dataGridView1.DataSource].Current).Row;
var index = r.Table.Rows.IndexOf(r);
```

In case you are interested to do that for all rows in the `DataGridView`, as also is mentioned by Taw in comments, you can look into the `DataBoundItem` of the `DataGridViewRow`:

```
var r = ((DataRowView)dgvRow.DataBoundItem).Row; // dgvRow is a row of the DataGridView
var index = r.Table.Rows.IndexOf(r);
```

Comment: In playing with the task of displaying __all__ the original rowindices in the rowheaders I came up with this one `index = ((DataView)dataGridView2.DataSource).Table.Rows.IndexOf(((DataRowView)row.DataBoundItem).Row);` where row is the DGV row.

Comment: Hi Guys,i cant seem to get the dgvrow above. And for the 1st code, i get rowindex based on filter and not the original index. Please bear with me as i'm only starting to learn programming. Thanks.

Comment: @newbie For the second solution, dgvRow can be any of the rows, for example `dataGridView1.CurrentCell.OwningRow` which is current row.

Comment: For the first option if you set the filter correctly, it will be working well. For example if `dt` is the `DataTable`, first set data source of the `DataGridView` this way `dataGridView1.DataSource = dt`, then to filter just set `dataGridView1.DefaultView.RowFilter = "your filter string"`. Then apply the code which I shared whenever you need to get the index of the current row.

Comment: Hi guys,i cant still get the original rowindex.

Comment: It can not be easier or more clear. I have no idea about what you are doing wrong unless you show us what you are doing to fill and then filter.

Comment: Here is what i'm doing: i have 8 records as follows per column of name and age--->name1,1;name2,2;...;name8,8.then i entered name3 on textbox as filter,so my current datagrid shows only 1 record which is name3,3. Now i have messagebox to display the details:record number,name & age. And the result is record number:zero;name:name3;age3. Record number should be 3 and not zero

Comment: To learn how to filter data grid view, take a look at [How to apply Filter to `DataGridView`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34347874/3110834)

Answer (score 0):

From your comments you said that you need it to display current record selected so I will not directly answer `How to get row index on filtered table` but `how to get current record selected`.

So to simply get current selected record use this code:

```
//Use this one if your datagridview SelectionMode is not FullRowSelect
DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex];
string name = row.Cells["Name"].Value.ToString();
int age = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["Age"].Value);


//If your datagridview SelectionMode is FullRowSelect then use this
DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0];
string name = row.Cells["Name"].Value.ToString();
int age = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["Age"].Value);
```

Reza answered main part of your question but if for some reason it is not working you can use this since your primary key is your `NAME`

```
foreach(DataRow r in yourDataTable.Rows)
{
    if(r["NAME"].ToString() == row.Cells["Name"].Value.ToString()) //This row.cells... is the one from above code
    {
        int originalRowIndexInDataTable = dt.Rows.IndexOf(r);
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly. The only thing missing is how will I display the record number of this. Assuming this is my 3rd record out of 8 records. How will i display 3. Note that it displays 3 without filter but when i filter, it displays the row index of current filter. Thank you.

Comment: I want to ask you one more thing because maybe we can make it easier for you. Is there `primary key` in your `DataTable` you are bounding to dgv?

Comment: Yes,i used the name as the primary.