# Suggestions for more efficient filtering on large datagridview datasources

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, datatable

Explanation: I have a datagridview whose datasource is equal to a large datatable, of around 220k rows. The datatable has numbers mostly (numeric columns) and one column for datetime objects. The way I do filtering right now, is binding source filtering:

```
mBindingSource.Filter = Filter;
```

where Filter is the appropriate string to search. This method worked great and instantly for small datatables of 10-50 rows for example, but is painfully slow for the 220k row case. I imagine this is because this method has to go through all the rows of the datasource, and then do its work.

How can I improve the efficiency of this filtering? I am open to any good suggestions, and any that might require to use something different than the bindingSource filter.

A second question is: Does anyone know how Excel implements its filtering? I tried the filtering on Excel for the same size datatable and the search was almost instant.

Edit: Adding the code that does the filtering (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33786/DataGridView-Filter-Popup). It basically takes tha datagridview's datasource and turns it into a dataview, it also checks if there is a binding source. On initialization it creates a list of dgvbasecolumnfilters, which serve as the base for the filters. Tihs means it creates one filter for every column of the datagridview, but I only have a few (30) columns so that shouldn't be an issue. In the end, when the user presses OK to apply the filters, this happens:

```
public void RebuildFilter() {
        mFilterIsActive = false;
        string Filter = "";
        foreach (DgvBaseColumnFilter CF in mColumnFilterList) {
            if (CF == null) continue;
            if (CF.Active && CF.FilterExpression != "") {
                Filter += " AND (" + CF.FilterExpression + ")";
                CF.DataGridViewColumn.HeaderText = CF.FilterCaption;
            }
            else {
                CF.DataGridViewColumn.HeaderText = CF.OriginalDataGridViewColumnHeaderText;
            }

        }
        if (Filter != "") {
            mFilterIsActive = true;
            Filter = (mBaseFilter == "") ? "1=1 " + Filter : mBaseFilter + " " + Filter;
        }
        else
            Filter = mBaseFilter;

        // Apply the filter only if any changes occurred
        try {
            if (mBindingSource != null) {
                if (mBindingSource.Filter != Filter) mBindingSource.Filter = Filter;
            } else 
            {
                if (mBoundDataView.RowFilter != Filter)mBoundDataView.RowFilter = Filter;
            }
        } catch { Console.WriteLine ("Invalid filter: " + Filter);}

    }
```

Comment: add some code of how you filter pls

Comment: There are suggestions like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843537/filtering-datagridview-without-changing-datasource) SO anwer. Also pagination could be an option too where you only select and display a set of amount of records in your grid.

Comment: Your data are stored in a database?

Comment: @erikscandola No, no database in play here.

Comment: Do you populate the datagrid with `List` of objects?

Comment: @nozzleman It's literally what I posted. The rest is how the user picks the options for filtering on the dialog, which I think is irrelevant to efficiency.

Comment: @erikscandola The datagridview is populated with numbers mostly, and one column for datetime objects. I will add it to my original question.

Comment: @lason I recommend you to post another question with the excel specific informations.

Comment: @kayess Under what tag should I do this?

Comment: @Iason I think [excel] and [filtering] should be fair enough. Although I'm not sure if it hasn't been asked already, might worth a search here...

Comment: `BindingSource.Filter` (which in turn uses `DataView.RowFilter`) is indeed the best for your case. What do you mean by "painfully slow"? I've tried data table with 500K rows and it works with a reasonable speed (less than a second). There must be something in your filters or column data types. Can you provide a working sample that presents the issue?

Comment: @IvanStoev My datatable has mostly numeric data and a datetime. I am acutally using the implementation of DgvFilterPopup (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33786/DataGridView-Filter-Popup) which uses bindingsource.filter and then dataview.rowfilter. I also checked out another implementation( http://davidegironi.blogspot.cz/2014/05/a-net-winform-datagridview-with.html?showComment=1449959045196#c1724718309303708397) but it's even slower. I will next post a small snippet of how the former does its work, or you can also check it if you want.

Comment: @IvanStoev New edit on my original question added. If you need more of this code to understand, please tell me.

Comment: Nothing special in that code. So you are saying that this line `mBindingSource.Filter = Filter;` executes slow? In my test (again with   500K rows) I've used a simple text box and was entering the filter string manually (vs automatically building it like this component). And it's working normally. Sorry, can't duplicate, thus have no idea.

Comment: @IvanStoev I stepped through the code, and you are right. RowFilter should be fast. I am pretty sure it's much slower because I'm painting the cells:                                                                                                               private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
        {
            //if ((e.RowIndex % 2) == 0)
            //    e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.NavajoWhite;         
        }  When I commented this out, my code became almost one magnitude faster. Do you know of a way to make painting faster?

Comment: Hmm, try limit cell level events in general. Btw, you should check the performance in release build outside the VS (from exe). What about the concrete code, if you need alternating row colors, better adjust the  `DataGridView.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle` properties once (at design time or during the form load)