# Implement filtering like excel (performance wise) in large datagridview datasource

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview, filtering

This question comes as a separate question from [Suggestions for more efficient filtering on large datagridview datasources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34629411/suggestions-for-more-efficient-filtering-on-large-datagridview-datasources/34629894#34629894). So right now my filtering is slow on large datasources (220k rows). The way I filter is by binding source:

```
mBindingSource.Filter = Filter;
```

This is slow because it possibly goes through all the rows of the datatable.

When I try to filter the same size of data in Excel, the filtering is many times faster. I would like to know whether someone knows, or can point me to the right direction as to how Excel implements its filtering. Maybe a snippet of code could also help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have a `dataGridView` full of rows it is very fast to filter.  Your problem is probably that you are reloading the `dataGridView` before you are applying the filter.

I did a test with a database with +800K rows and it filters in less than a second (Maybe Excel will take longer).

This is how I tested:

Take the table from the Data Sources window and drag it and drop it on your `Form`.  In my case I'm taking a table called Products.

[image: Products dataGridView]

That creates a `dataGridView` on your `Form` named `productsDataGridView` so the CS code was like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BindingSource bs = (BindingSource)productsDataGridView.DataSource;

    bs.Filter = string.Format("SerialNumber Like  '%{0}%'", textBox1.Text);

    productsDataGridView.DataSource = bs;
}
```

In my case, every time I press the `button1` the `productsDataGridView` that has more than 820,000 rows was filtered in less than a second.

I hope this helps you debug your code.

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look at this as soon as possible.

Comment: This is much better than before. By the way, what do you mean by reloading the datagridview before applying the filter?

Comment: By reloading I meant to have the `Fill()` function loading the **dataSet** where the **dataGridView** is taking the data from.  May be something like this: `this.productsTableAdapter.Fill(this.dataSet1.Products);`