# Filtering a datagridview after importing from excel via a text box in vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, excel, datagridview

I have a datagridview which i import an excel file in to it. My excel columns are name,id,sex,grade,seat no,permanent address,temporary address and phone number.What i want is to filter all the columns at the same time (multi column filter) in the datagridview via a single textbox. i.e. when i type a single word in the text box i want it to filter the columns  at the same time.

Here is the code i got to import the excel to the datagridview....

```
Dim cn As New OleDbConnection
Dim cm As New OleDbCommand
Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter
Dim dt As New DataTable
Private Excel03ConString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR={1}'"
Private Excel07ConString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR={1}'"
Private Sub btnSelect_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSelect.Click
OpenFileDialog1.Title = "Open Internship Excel Files"

OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
End Sub
Private Sub OpenFileDialog1_FileOk(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles OpenFileDialog1.FileOk
        Dim filePath As String = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
        Dim extension As String =
        Path.GetExtension(filePath)
        Dim header As String = If(rbHeaderYes.Checked, "YES", "NO")
        Dim conStr As String, sheetName As String
        conStr = String.Empty
        Select Case extension
            Case ".xls"
                'Excel 97-03
                conStr = String.Format(Excel03ConString, filePath, header)
                Exit Select
            Case ".xlsx"
                'Excel 07
                conStr = String.Format(Excel07ConString, filePath, header)
                Exit Select
        End Select
        'Get the name of the First Sheet.
        Using con As New OleDbConnection(conStr)
            Using cmd As New OleDbCommand()
                cmd.Connection = con
                con.Open()
                Dim dtExcelSchema As DataTable = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, Nothing)
                sheetName = dtExcelSchema.Rows(0)("TABLE_NAME").ToString()
                con.Close()
            End Using
        End Using
        'Read Data from the First Sheet.
        Using con As New OleDbConnection(conStr)
            Using cmd As New OleDbCommand()
                Using oda As New OleDbDataAdapter()
                    Dim dt As New DataTable()
                    cmd.CommandText = (Convert.ToString("SELECT * From [") & sheetName) + "]"
                    cmd.Connection = con
                    con.Open()
                    oda.SelectCommand = cmd
                    oda.Fill(dt)
                    con.Close()
                    'Populate DataGridView.
                    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub
```

Comment: What have you done so far and where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: so far i only did importing the excel file in to the datagridview with the code i have shown above.and also i have a text box (txtfilter). I am stuck in coding the text change event of the textbox ie. the code for the text change event of the text box.

Comment: You need to think this thru and explain better.  Rows are filtered, not columns.  The criteria for filtering the Gender wont have much in common with criteria for Id.

Comment: ok sorry, i meant to say filtering the rows.We can ignore the id.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a row filter like this: (From [Filtering DataGridView without changing datasource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843537/filtering-datagridview-without-changing-datasource))

```
CType(DataGridView1.DataSource,DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = MyQueryCriteria
```

For your criteria you'll want something like:

```
Dim MyQueryCriteria = String.Format("ID like '%{0}%' OR NAME like '%{0}%' OR ...", MyTextBox.Text)
```

You may run into issues with types there but [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.110).aspx) has information on conversions.