# searching gridview in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to look for a way to search a grid view in asp.net using C# programming language. I dont want the grid view to have paging enabled. I would like it to bring up the result of the input typed in. E.g. If i typed in 's', all records starting with s would only be visible.

I have looked up on some sites which have databind in the code.

```
GridView1.DataSource = dt;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Do I need to have this? What does this do?

Can I please get some help with advice or links that can answer my question. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, you need to bind data to your grid in order for it to display rows. The object dt should be a data table. You then filter (search) on the datatable and rebind to display the matching results. Here is a related post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843537/filtering-datagridview-without-changing-datasource

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete working example. You way want to tweak it a bit to suit your own needs. And as Murray Foxcroft pointed out you will find several `DataBindings` in this example to make things work.

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="searchBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="searchButton" runat="server" Text="search" OnClick="searchButton_Click" />
    <asp:Button ID="reset" runat="server" Text="reset" OnClick="resetSearchButton_Click" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="field01" HeaderText="Column A" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="field02" HeaderText="Column B" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="field03" HeaderText="Column C" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

And in code behind;

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //to make sure the data isn't loaded in postback
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            //use a datatable for storing all the data
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            string query = "SELECT * FROM myTable ORDER BY myColumn DESC";

            //wrapping in 'using' means the connection is closed an disposed when done
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("myConnectionString"))
            using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connection))
            {
                try
                {
                    //fill the datatable with the contents from the database
                    adapter.Fill(dt);
                }
                catch
                {
                }
            }

            //save the datatable into a viewstate for later use
            ViewState["myViewState"] = dt;

            //bind the datasource to the gridview
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void searchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string searchTerm = searchBox.Text.ToLower();

        //check if the search input is at least 3 chars
        if (searchTerm.Length >= 3)
        {
            //always check if the viewstate exists before using it
            if (ViewState["myViewState"] == null)
                return;

            //cast the viewstate as a datatable
            DataTable dt = ViewState["myViewState"] as DataTable;

            //make a clone of the datatable
            DataTable dtNew = dt.Clone();

            //search the datatable for the correct fields
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                //add your own columns to be searched here
                if (row["field01"].ToString().ToLower().Contains(searchTerm) || row["field02"].ToString().ToLower().Contains(searchTerm))
                {
                    //when found copy the row to the cloned table
                    dtNew.Rows.Add(row.ItemArray);
                }
            }

            //rebind the grid
            GridView1.DataSource = dtNew;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }


    protected void resetSearchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //always check if the viewstate exists before using it
        if (ViewState["myViewState"] == null)
            return;

        //cast the viewstate as a datatable
        DataTable dt = ViewState["myViewState"] as DataTable;

        //rebind the grid
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

> Note that this searching of GridViews is probably only efficient with
> little amounts of data. If you are talking about 1000+ rows it would
> be much better to search the source (database) and bind those to the
> grid.
>
> Note 2: Searching GridView cells like this (Rows[0].Cells[1].Text)
> only works with BoundField columns, not TemplateField and
> AutoGenerated Columns.

Comment: Are there any .. considerations for storing 500+ rows of data in ViewState? Any performance/security issues that should be known? What is the benefit in using the ViewState in this way? I'm assuming to prevent loading the data from the database multiple times since the server already has it in ViewState?

Comment: It depends on how many data those 500 rows contain (2 columns vs 200). But you need to know that all data is stored in the ViewState by default. The ViewState is encoded, send to the client, send back to the server with a PostBack and then decoded. So if the total data is 100kb then 200kb of extra trafic is generated. And it takes time to encode and decode the data.

Comment: For that reason I disabled ViewState , it offers a great performance boost, and once you're used to working without life becomes much better. The only difference being that the database is called with every request instead of just once and then stored in ViewState, but if the database is set up correctly, the Indexes made etc then it will be faster.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. So it seems that querying a healthy database multiple times would be a better idea than banging the web server and network with viewstate. Very good. The data size for my scenario is a single database table with (as of now) 1000 rows of data and each row has like 8 columns. Not huge. Simple intranet web page to search one dataset by a user ID and get some info on the system.

Comment: One more question - why do you clone the datatable?

Comment: To get an exact copy of the original so that you can add the rows that have the search term to the new table. You could also use `Linq` on the datatable without cloning and looping all the rows. Both work.

Comment: or you can just hide the rows that don't match with `display:none`

Answer (score 1):

You can use "DataTable" javascript functionality for this problem. Please refer https://www.datatables.net/.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#GridView1').DataTable();
});
```

only set your table id here and it will automatically set pagination, sorting, filtering of your table.

Thanks