# C# Datagridview filter using textbox and button

Tags: c#, search, datagridview

I want to filter my datagridview using click event, I'm using the following code:

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
        bs.DataSource = dataGridView3.DataSource;
        bs.Filter = dataGridView3.Columns[0].HeaderText.ToString() + " LIKE '%" + textBox1.Text + "%'";
        dataGridView3.DataSource = bs;
```

This works for my other datagridviews, but it shows an error for this `datagridview3`: `Cannot perform 'Like' operation on System.Int32 and System.String`.

Here is the datagridview3 in a screenshot to show which data it is holding:

[image]

Comment: Can you please add **more information**, e.g.: on what data and datatypes there are in your `datagridview` -and if possible a screenshot or a repo where we can clone your application.

Comment: so this is for the datagridview http://imgur.com/a/0ZYev

Comment: OH, IT WORKED ! THANKYOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have to convert the value you get from `textBox1.Text` to a number. the data in the first column is numeric, and this comparing text (`string`) vs a numeric value isn't supported.

Here are some ways of converting to an integer value:

```
int anInteger;
anInteger = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
anInteger = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
```

Once you have succesfully converted, you can adapt your code and try to see if it works that way:

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
        bs.DataSource = dataGridView3.DataSource;
        bs.Filter = dataGridView3.Columns[0].HeaderText.ToString() + " LIKE '%" + Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) + "%'";
        dataGridView3.DataSource = bs;
```

**NOTE**: Make sure to **check** whether the use has entered a valid number before hitting the search button ofcourse. Otherwise you'll still receive an error that the value couldn't be parsed/converted to a number.

Hope all of this helps you a bit more.

Comment: THANK YOU.. IT WORKS NOW..
I JUST CHANGED my STRUCTURE TO VARCHAR 
i can't search it because it was INT in my database..

Comment: true, there must be something else.. It's a long time for me since I worked with dataGridView and it's filter method.. Maybe try looking into other questions on SO, or even this specific one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843537/filtering-datagridview-without-changing-datasource

Comment: oh ok, glad ;)! That's why we need as much info as we can when you post a question. From your code, to screenshots to db structure (I forgot to ask). Glad it worked, happy to help. Have a nice coding day ;)