# import csv to datagridview filter

Tags: c#, csv, datagridview, filter

My question is that how can I filter the content of the columns.
I have a column like 'Spinbase TrackingState', i have two options 'tracked' and 'nottracked'
I want to load, which includes only 'Tracked'.
Thanks your help!:)

```
namespace LoadFromCsv
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public DataTable ReadCsv(string filePath)
    {
        var dt = new DataTable();
        List<string> cols = File.ReadLines(filePath).Take(1)
            .SelectMany(x => x.Split(new[] { ';' }))
            .ToList();
        for (int i = 0; i < cols.Count; i++)
        {
            string colName = cols[i].Trim();
            //Debug.Print(colName);
            int num = 1;

            for (int j = i+1; j < cols.Count; j++)
            {
                if (cols[i] == cols[j])
                {
                    //Debug.Print(string.Format("({0},{1})", i, j));
                    cols[j] = string.Format("{0}_{1}", cols[i], ++num);
                    Debug.Print(string.Format("{0} -> {1}", cols[i], cols[j]));
                }
            }

            /*
            while (dt.Columns.Contains(colName))
            {
                Debug.Print(string.Format("{0} -> {1}", num, colName));
                colName = string.Format("{0}_{1}", cols[i], ++num);
                Debug.Print(colName);
            }
            dt.Columns.Add(colName.Trim());
            //cols[i] = colName;
        */        
        }
        cols.ForEach(x => dt.Columns.Add(x.Trim()));

        File.ReadLines(filePath).Skip(1)
            .Select(x => x.Split(';'))
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(line => dt.Rows.Add(line));

        return dt;

    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            using (OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog() { Filter = "CSV|*.csv", ValidateNames = true, Multiselect = false })
            {
                if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = ReadCsv(ofd.FileName);

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It seems you are already importing the lines to the DataTable. Cant you just query it off of the DataTable, or filter your return?

Comment: It is unclear what the data contains. Is there a single column in the csv file named “Spinbase TrakingState” and the values for that column are true/false/tracked/untracked? It appears you may be describing a true (tracked) or false (not tracked) value for this column which would point to a `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn`. Without more information about how the original data is structured and what exactly you want the grid to look like, speculation may be all anyone can offer.

Comment: You may want to read the [Help](http://stackoverflow.com/help)  section to see how SO works, and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) AND [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Yes, It's a single column named "Spinbase TrackingState" value(tracked,nottracked), and i want to load that rows where it's 'tracked'.

http://imgur.com/a/k0B8x

There is a picture, i want to load only tracked rows.
Thanks your help!

Comment: Since the column appears to contain the string values “Tracked” or “Not Tracked” you can either: Only read in the rows that have the “Tacked” string into the `DataTable` OR a better solution is to do as @Surgeon of Death suggested and simply query/filter the original `DataTable`.

Comment: Since the column appears to be a string... have you tried clicking on the "SpineBase TrackingState" column header? This should group all the "Tracked" and "Not Tracked" values together.

Comment: Yes it's an easier way, but i have to do, that only load tracked rows, it's my task in my school.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filtering DataGridView without changing datasource](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843537/filtering-datagridview-without-changing-datasource)