# How to search datagrid box using textbox

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have dataGridView which filled with data from .csv file, I need to be able to search in textbox and filter the data as I write in textbox.
I tried few times with this code but no luck so far:

```
(dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = 
    string.Format("City='{0}%'", textBox1.Text);
```

Comment: Have you tried solutions from [Filtering DataGridView without changing datasource](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843537/filtering-datagridview-without-changing-datasource)?

Comment: I found something similar somewhere else with the same code that worked for me, thanks

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to find my mistake, the correct code is:

```
(dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("City LIKE'{0}%'", textBox1.Text);
```

now it is working absolutely fine.