# Check if DataGridView Contains specific word

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm currently doing a school project and I need to know how to check if in any row of the datagridview contains a specific word in any column, and hide the rows that don't contain that word, in any column.
I have no code yet, just the datagridview and the textbox on the form.

Comment: why not filtering in sql itself

Comment: is this what you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843537/filtering-datagridview-without-changing-datasource

Comment: @BhubanShrestha because the objective it's to populate the datagridview with everything and if the user wants he will be able to filter to find some record easily

Comment: easy way would be filtering grid view data source (data table) using linq and reassigning filtered result a data source to grid view

Comment: @BhubanShrestha The problem is that I don't know how to do that :\ Can you give me the code to that?

Comment: Search in google there are numbers of QA regarding this issue in SO itself.

Comment: @BhubanShrestha I've been searching for around 3 hours, and still no answer

Comment: @grepLines Thanks ! I've found something closer, but I need to get if there's for example a piece of a word, not the full word, something .Contains, but I don't know how to use that

`(dataGridViewFields.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter  = string.Format("Field = '{0}'", textBoxFilter.Text);`

But now I have a problem, if I clean my textbox doesn't show anything on my datagridview

Comment: @A.Conde which datasource are you using: DataTable, DataBinding or DataSet?

Comment: You should try to find out yourself using google. Imo coding is about finding answers, not about asking questions to make other people give you answers. Filtering a datagridview is very basic - For the purpose of learning to code it's important that you find that on your own. Also this platform is not meant to be a coding service. Give us some code that you have tried and we will tell you why its not working, but do not ask us to write your code. Greetings

Comment: @Luke I was asking because I had no ideia how to do that type of code, but I've found the answer, Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only want to filter when the textbox is NOT not null or empty string(make sure you trim the string to remove leading and trailing white space).

```
 (dataGridViewFields.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("columnname like '%{0}%'", textBoxFilter.Text);
```

- Filter expressions

  - `columnname like '%{0}%'` means  columnname contains specific word/string.
  - `columnname not like '%{0}%` means NOT contains

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are using `DataTable` as `DataSource`.

When you are passing the `TextBox.Text`as `RowFilter` and clear it, it becomes an empty string.

In the `TextChanged` event, just check if the TextBox is empty. Your event would look something like this:

```
private void textBoxFilter_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text))
    {
        (dataGridViewFields.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Field = '{0}'", textBoxFilter.Text);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate all the rows and cells,
and hide the row if your keyword found in a cell,

```
private void HideRow(string word)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
        {
            var value = Convert.ToString(cell.Value);
            if (word != value)
            {
                row.Visible = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

call this method wherever you want, on `TextChanged` Event or `ButtonClick`

Comment: Row.visible = false will cause Currencymanager exceptions. You want to set the .Currentcell to NULL first.