# How to display the count value on label?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, count, display

I have a monitoring in datagridview that has a display of list of vehicles and their types. I want to count the number of each type of the vehicle.

Example : there are 8 Sedans and 5 Motorcycles in the datagridview and I want it to display in the label.

here is my code:

```vb
Dim table As New DataTable()

Dim command As New MySqlCommand("select count(ctype) from tblreport where ctype='SUV'", conn)

command.Parameters.Add("count(ctype)", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Label6.Text

Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter(command)

adapter.Fill(table)

DataGridView2.DataSource = table
```

Comment: You dont need to fill a DataTable to get a Scalar value (SELECT COUNT()).  And that Parameter wont do you much good since teh SQL has no params. Putting text onto a label is just the reverse of how you are getting *something* from the label.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: how can I display the value (SELECT COUNT())?

Comment: First, you need to get the value from the DB and I am not sure that code will do it. You should do some research on the DB Provider objects you are trying to use.  Read [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 0):

After you assign the datasource, just add this :

```
 Label1.Text=datagridview1.rows.count
```

`Text` is a property of many controls like label,button and others.This property can be used to display an overlay of text over the control. `Datagridview` has rows ,right ? So, as u said, u want to display the number of rows the datagridview contains.So all you need to do is use `Datagridview1.rows.count`,i don't think this one needs any explanation at all.

Anyway, let's advance a bit further.

You also said

> there are 8 Sedans and 5 Motorcycles in the datagridview and I want it to display in the label.

By default,no application can understand how many records match **Sedans** and **Motorcycles** .But as mentioned above, vb is able to calculate the rows of a datagridview(by default/by simple codes).So try to think for once,if the datagridview only had the rows that contained **Sedans** or **Motorcycles** in any cell, vb.net could've easily counted it..right ??

So, if u ask me, how do we get only the rows containing **Sedans** or **Motors** , then i'ld as u, how does google show only the results u r looking for instead of showing everything it has ?? The answer is simple,google shows exactly what you **Search** for. When it comes to databases,we call it filtering/sorting/even seaching.So, all you need to do is filter your database.There are couple of ways,which,if i start explaining,would take a lotta time.However,check these :

• http://csharp.net-informations.com/datagridview/csharp-datagridview-filter.htm

• [Filtering DataGridView without changing datasource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843537/filtering-datagridview-without-changing-datasource)

Now, let's go deeper.If you go through the links above,you'll be able to show only the rows that contain **Sedans** or so in any of it's cells.What if you want all the rows but only want the label to display the number(row count) of **Sedans** or so ?

In this case,you can use a `Datatable`.

[Learn more about Datatable here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.110).aspx)

You can easily use a datatable to count the rows containg only the **QUERY** u r looking for.For that, u can code as follows :

```
 Dim cmd as new MySqlCommand("Select * from [tablename](columnname)(@value)",con)

 cmd.parametres.addwithvalue("@value","Sedan")
 Dim table as new DataTable
 Dim adap as new MySqlDataAdapter
 adap.fill(table)

 If table.rows.count <=0 then

   Else

  LAbel1.text=table.rows.count
```

Let me explain from `dim table`.Here i am declaring a datatable.But before that i am filtering the dataset by using `cmd.parametres.addwithvalue`.Then,i am using a `DataAdapter` and filling the `DataTable` with only th e rows containing **SEDAN**. Now, focus on `If table.Rows.Count <=0 Then` ...This indicates if there are no rows(which is less than or equals to 0) containing the query.Then i am using the `Else` statement which means if the datatable contains rows matching the query.In the else statement,i am adding the row count of the `Datatable` as a string/text in the `Label`..

I hope this is enough and this explanation will help u in future as well.

Comment: raylan  Lots of good thinking material here. The OP's use of cmd.parameters.Add is a bit safer than .AddWithValue. See https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: Your command isnt used anywhere? Should the adapter know about its command?

Answer (score 0):

Use the same DataTable you have used to fill the DataGridView. Only change your select statement to Select * from tableName. I used the index of 2 but change to whatever it is in your table. The column index starts at zero.

```
        Dim totalSedans As Integer = 0
        Dim totalMotorcycles As Integer = 0
        Dim totalConvertable As Integer = 0
        For Each row As DataRow In table.Rows
            Select Case row(2).ToString
                Case "Sedan"
                    totalSedans += 1
                Case "Motorcycle"
                    totalMotorcycles += 1
                Case "Convertable"
                    totalConvertable += 1
                Case Else
                    Debug.Print("Something doesn't match categories")
            End Select
        Next
        lblConvertable.Text = totalConvertable.ToString
        lblMotorcycles.Text = totalMotorcycles.ToString
        lblSedan.Text = totalSedans.ToString
```