# Filter GridView through TextBox without loosing the checkBox inside the grid in c#

Tags: c#, checkbox, datagridview, filtering

i have this problem about DataGridView with checkbox inside. i populate the gridview by using a data table and pass it to the binding source.
[image]

the problem starts here when i search on the textbox, all the checkbox become unchecked.
[image]

here is my code in filtering the grid using textbox

```
BindingSource bs;
bs.Filter = string.Format("NAME LIKE '%{0}%'", txtSearch.Text);
```

Edited: I also use the rowFilter and still fails.

```
 DataView dv = (dgvGrid.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView;
 dv.RowFilter = string.Format("NAME LIKE '%{0}%'", txtSearch.Text);
```

Comment: This may not be the same exact issue, but this link may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843537/filtering-datagridview-without-changing-datasource

Comment: thank you but i already read that and apply it and still the checkbox becomes uncheck where i try to filter. I spend how many days cracking this one.

Comment: I believe the issue has to be in the data grid getting rebound to the modified datasource when you are trying to filter all the check boxes getting reinitialized. The Select column, is it a bound column or and unbound column?

Comment: You are missing an important part that Priyan Perera asked about and I am guessing the check box column is NOT part of the data source. If the check box column is NOT bound to the data source and you create the check box column externally from the data source, then you will have to keep track of which check boxes are checked when sorting. If you add a Boolean column to the data source, then problem solved.

Comment: sorry for late response Priyan Perera, as  JohnG stated he is correct, now i been trying to do the same as he suggested and I'll give you my feedback once im done
Edit: Thanks JohnG it works i hope you can post that as an answer.