# Advanced DataGridView problem with sorting and checkbox

Tags: c#, datagridview

Recenlty I was searching for option that allow me to had "excel like" filtering in my app that use DataGridView.
So I found something like Advanced DataGridView (https://github.com/davidegironi/advanceddatagridview)

Almost everything is working fine, but I had 2 issues with it:

1. In the datagirdview I have a column that is checkbox. For each row is allowing user to checking rows that needs to be imported to order in our ERP. But if user select some on checkboxes and next want to filtered list all checkboxes will be in uncheck state. How can I made it working?
2. In default datagridview column sorting were working fine, after switching to Advanced DataGridView, sorting stoped working but filtering is working fine. How to made both of them working?

I populate DataTable with SQL query and put DataTable in DataGridView.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48819799/filter-gridview-through-textbox-without-loosing-the-checkbox-inside-the-grid-in
Is this the problem you are saying. If so please check the 4th comment from JohnG. Hope it helps.

Comment: Check out [DataGridView Filter Popup](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33786/DataGridView-Filter-Popup) which may be viable for filtering and sorting.

Comment: @JyothishBhaskaran Yea its helped, but there is also a bug,, if I check 4 rows and change filter then last checked checkbox will change status to unchecked one.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @JyothishBhaskaran, yours comment helped me with checkbox issue.
Meanwhile I found solution for last checked box changed to unchecked status. I had to call method datagridview.endedit() on cell click.

But sorting still isn't working at all.