# How to filter a range of value in a gridview in c#.net

Tags: c#, .net, c#-1.2

I am a beginner in c#, is there any possibility to filter a particular range of integer value from a gridview of a particular column ?

Comment: You're using C# 1.2???

Comment: might be this useful to you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843537/filtering-datagridview-without-changing-datasource

Comment: No sorry I wrongly tagged that

Answer (score 0):

```
//Assuming the datasource of the grid is inputData
var filtered = inputData.Where(someValue => 
    (someValue >=vMin && omeValue <=vMax));
```