# Updating DataSource for DataGridView when DataSource set in properties

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, dataset, datasource

I have a `DataGridView` and have set the DataSource (dataset DsAll) and columns in the `DataGridView` properties.

Now i want to update the source/dataset. That is, I want to be able to limit or expand the data records shown in the grid, by putting a value in a `TextBox` and searching for only those records where that value is in a particular field (for instance employee id or department number,  etc...)

I got this to work when I manually set the DataSource/bindings but I'am having issues when using the properties to set the DataSource.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Check out row filters. edit: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843537/filtering-datagridview-without-changing-datasource

Comment: You should bind your `DataTable` to a `BindingSource` and then bind that to the grid.  You would then set the `Filter` property of that `BindingSource`.  The actual filter string is formatted just as for the `DefaultView.RowFilter` of a `DataTable` but it's a neater way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on my comment, I suggest adding a `BindingSource` in the designer and then binding something like this:

```
myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataTable)
myBindingSource.DataSource = myDataTable
myDataGridView.DataSource = myBindingSource
```

and then filtering something like this:

```
myBindingSource.Filter = String.Format("MyColumn LIKE '%{0}%'", myTextBox.Text)
```