# C# How to display in datagridview the selected date value in datetimepicker

Tags: c#, winforms

To be more precise. Here's I'm trying to achieve. My database has date column with dates value, Now i have a datetimepicker if i select a date let's say for example August 21, 2018, all row that has a date of august 21, should be displayed only. I need help in doing these, i really don't know how i'm gonna do that. Thank you

Here's the provided code that i tried but it doesn't work

PS: Date column is varchar datatype in my database

```
public partial class SIMSSupplier : UserControl
{
    ADDSupplier supply;
    ADDPReturns returns;
    public SIMSSupplier()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
    public DataTable dbdataset;
   private void FillSupplier(DataGridView grid, string request)
    {
        using (var con = SQLConnection.GetConnection())
        using (var select = new SqlCommand(request, con))
        using (var sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
        {
            dbdataset = new DataTable();
            sda.SelectCommand = select;
            sda.Fill(dbdataset);
            grid.DataSource = new BindingSource() { DataSource = dbdataset };
            sda.Update(dbdataset);
        }
    }
 private void DateReturn_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       var dv = new DataView(dbdataset);
        dv.RowFilter = string.Format("Date LIKE '%{0}%'", DateReturn2.Value);
        PurchaseReturn.DataSource = dv;
    }
}
```

Comment: what's in `dbdataset`?

Comment: check the value from `new DateTime(selecteddate.Day, selecteddate.Month, selecteddate.Year).ToString()`. I think it is not in format as  `August 21, 2018`.

Comment: Where i bind my database, see the updated code above

Comment: See the updated code above

Comment: @Anonymous what is the value coming from `DateReturn2.Value` and do you have that particular value in the `DataGridView` field `Date`. and if the values match try something like this:`(PurchaseReturn.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Date LIKE '%{0}%'", DateReturn2.Value);` and for more info have a look at [Filtering DataGridView without changing datasource](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5843537/2417602).

Comment: I have to ask, why on earth would you define a datecolumn as varchar ?

Answer (score 1):

I will say that there is only ONE solution to this and i will explain it why.

Problem is that your date is formatted in database as `varchar`, solution is to change it to `date` or `datetime`

Reason why you MUST change it is because when you are passing date to database in format of `varchar` there is possibility you would pass it from one function like `dd/MM/yyyy` and from other as `MM/dd/yyyy` and then in database you would have 2 dates with different formats which is impossible to filter through.

Reason i said it is THE ONLY solution is because even if you solve this problem with custom functions you will make 2 problems:

- You will come to same problem next time you use some data from that database
- You will make confusion inside your code and when you come to the point you have so much custom functions and extensions you will forget how you named/used that one and when you google how to fix problem everywhere will be solutions that are already inside `.Net` or something else and again you will not have solution to that problem.