# C# Datagridview Timestamp (Monday-Friday) & (8 am - 3 pm)

Tags: c#, datagridview

So I have a datagrid with a timestamp for each row & the timestamp is everyday and everyhour of the week. I am having trouble rearranging the datagrid to have only Monday to Friday & 8 am to 3 pm timestamps. Does anyone know how to rearrange a column to get only times that are Monday through Friday (8 am to 3 pm)? [Datagrid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtGen.jpg)

```
try
            {
                var endTimeInclusive = DateTime.UtcNow;
                var startTimeInclusive = 
endTimeInclusive.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromHours(hours));

                var bars = client.ListMinuteAggregatesAsync(symbol, 
startTimeInclusive, endTimeInclusive).Result;


                this.Invoke(new Action(delegate ()
                {
                    foreach (var bar in bars.Items)
                    {
                        alpaGrid.Rows.Add(bar.Time.ToString(), symbol, 
bar.Open, bar.High, bar.Low, bar.Close, bar.Volume);


                    }
                }));
            }
```

Comment: Is this winform?

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i = 0; i < alpaGrid.Rows; i++)
{
    DataGridViewRow row = alpaGrid.Rows[i];
    DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(row["Timestamp"].Value); //"Timestamp" is your column name

    if(date < .....)
        row.Visible = false;
    else
        row.Visible = true;
}
```

This way you will just hide your row from dataGridView but not delete it. Later if you want just do same loop but without any check `row.Visible = true;` and you will set all rows to be visible.

Also another approach is to use row filtering but not sure how will it work since i am using it only when i populate dataGridView with `dgv.DataSource = ...`

If you are interested in trying it out check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843537/filtering-datagridview-without-changing-datasource)