# Datarow as DataSource of DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datarow

```
public partial class Oef455 : Form
{
    dtsOef444 dtsOrders = new dtsOef444();
    dtsOef444TableAdapters.tblOrderinformatieTableAdapter TAOrderInfo = new dtsOef444TableAdapters.tblOrderinformatieTableAdapter();
    dtsOef444TableAdapters.tblOrdersTableAdapter TAOrders = new dtsOef444TableAdapters.tblOrdersTableAdapter();
    public Oef455()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void cbOrderID_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
        int OrderID = int.Parse(cbOrderID.SelectedValue.ToString());
        DataRow drOrders = dtsOrders.tblOrders.FindByOrderID(OrderID);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = drOrders;
    }

    private void Oef455_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TAOrderInfo.Fill(dtsOrders.tblOrderinformatie);
        TAOrders.Fill(dtsOrders.tblOrders);
        cbOrderID.ValueMember = "OrderID";
        cbOrderID.DisplayMember = "OrderID";
        cbOrderID.DataSource = dtsOrders.tblOrders;
    }
}
```

I am trying to show all the Orders with a selected OrderID (which you can select in a combobox) in a DataGridView, someone who can help me out? Because when I select a order in the combobox, the DataGridView doesn't change...

Comment: When I select a order in the combobox, the DataGridView doesn't change.

Comment: Edit your question and add this information. Is your combo binded?

Comment: I have never binded a single object or row to grid. It always has been a collection

Comment: The DGV is not repainting.  I would set to null like this : dataGridView1.DataSource = null;dataGridView1.DataSource = drOrders;

Comment: Step 1: put a breakpoint in SelectedIndexChanged and verify that it is called.

Comment: Well, I updated it with all my code, take a look.

Comment: Henk Holterman, I did and it got called, no succes so far.

Comment: Ok, a DataRow is a singleton (single row). DataSource expects a List of something. `dtsOrders.tblOrders.Where(o => o.Id == OrderID).ToList()` might show something. Debug to verify it isn't an empty list.

Comment: `FindByOrderID` should return a `DataTable` containing a single row. How you have written the code. Share the code.

Comment: @RezaAghaei : `DataRow drOrders` tells it all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```cs
private void cbOrderID_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
    int OrderID = int.Parse(cbOrderID.SelectedValue.ToString());
    DataRow drOrders = dtsOrders.tblOrders.FindByOrderID(OrderID);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = drOrders;
}
```

I assume your are using `TableAdapter` to populate the `DataGridView`.
Please try to `.Fill` them with the filtered table.

```cs
private void cbOrderID_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cbOrderID.SelectedValue != null){
        int OrderID = int.Parse(cbOrderID.SelectedValue.ToString());
        TAOrders.Fill(dtsOrders.tblOrders.FindByOrderID(OrderID));
    }
}
```

Maybe you have other `.Fill()`Functions for this TableAdapter.

### Another Method

Try `.DefaultView.RowFilter` this would filter without requerying the DataSource.
[StackOverflow - Filtering DataGridView without changing datasource](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10049875/1413718)

```cs
(dataGridViewFields.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Field = '{0}'", textBoxFilter.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way you can change the Data Source of DataGridView based on the ComboBox's selected item.

```
private void cbOrderID_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox combo = (sender as ComboBox);
    DataRowView selectedItem = (combo.SelectedItem as DataRowView);
    this.BindGrid(selectedItem);
}
private void BindGrid(DataRowView comboItem)
{
    int OrderID = (int)comboItem.Row["OrderID"];
    DataView view = new DataView(OrdersTable());
    view.RowFilter = string.Format("OrderID = {0}", OrderID);
    this.dataGridView1.DataSource = view;
}
```