# Filter Datagridview after importing using Combobox C#

Tags: c#, .net, filter, combobox

I have a datagridview1 with data imported from a excel file and there are 12 columns: date, Name, Activity, Project,time, comment,ect. and 1000 rows.
 What I want to do is to filter only all with the Project name in project column. for example I have support as a (Projectname) I want to show all columns filtyring by support rows. I have combobox to select which column I need to filter it( e.g Project) here, I tried with this code but it dose not work.
Any one can help me please:
Thank you!

```
private void ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    string projektItem = comboBox1.Items[comboBox1.SelectedIndex].ToString();
    if (projektItem == "Project") {
        foreach (DataRow dataRow in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            StringBuilder filter = new StringBuilder();

            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                filter.Append(dataRow[i].ToString());
                filter.Append("\t");
            }
            dataGridView1.DataSource = filter.ToString();
        }


    if (projektItem == "Name") {
    }
    if (projektItem == "Aktivity") {
    }


}
```

Comment: Have to datagridview1.databind()  And your datasource is string?

Comment: What you mean can you show me in the code please ?

Comment: one way to filer data, https://10tec.com/articles/datagridview-filter.aspx and https://stackoverflow.com/a/10049875/3350329

Comment: I have no database here it is just C# code, is this link works in my situation? my data imported from excel file.

Comment: it will works in your situation, put excel data in to DataTable, then use RowFilter to filter data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are using the comboBox to select what column is gonna be filtered with.

An easy way to filter data in a dataGridView is doing the following:

1. Get a DataTable with all the information you want to show.
2. Convert DataTable into DataView
3. Change RowFilter property of DataView to, for example, "Name = sth"
4. After applying filter, convert DataView back into DataTable
5. Use that DataTable as source for your DataGridView

What I like about this is that RowFilter allows you to filter in a very similar way to a SQL WHERE clausule