# Exception Thrown when typed in search textbox fast to change row selection of datagrid

Tags: c#, async-await, datagridview

**Scenario :** I want to change row selection of datagridview based on what I typed in search textbox. But everytime I typed fast, this error occurred **System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'**

Below is my code:

```
private async Task dgvScripturesChangeRowSelection() 
        {
                if (txtSearchReference.Text != string.Empty)
                {
                int rowIndex = -1;
                var changeRowSelection = await Task.Run(() =>
                    {
                    DataGridViewRow row = dgvScriptures.Rows
                        .Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                        .Where(r => r.Cells[1].Value.ToString().Contains(txtSearchReference.Text))
                        .FirstOrDefault();
                        rowIndex = row.Index;
                        return rowIndex;
                    });
                dgvScriptures.CurrentCell = dgvScriptures[1, changeRowSelection];
                }
                
        }
```

```
private void txtSearchReference_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                dgvScripturesChangeRowSelection();
            }
            catch (Exception autocomplete)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(autocomplete.ToString());
            }
            
        }
```

my database here is XML. here is the code how I load my data to datagridview

```
var bibleTranslation = cboTranslation.Text;

                XDocument xmlDocs = XDocument.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + bibleTranslation + ".xml");

                XElement xmlBible = xmlDocs.Descendants("XMLBIBLE").FirstOrDefault();
                string bibleName = (string)xmlBible.Attribute("biblename");

                var loadBible = await Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    var fetchBible = xmlDocs.Root.Descendants("BIBLEBOOK")

                    .SelectMany(x => x.Elements("CHAPTER"),
                    (book, chapter) => new
                    {
                        BookName = book.Attribute("bname").Value,
                        Chapter = chapter
                    })
                    .SelectMany(x => x.Chapter.Elements("VERS"),
                    (chapter, verse) => new
                    {
                        BookName = chapter.BookName,
                        ChapterNumber = chapter.Chapter.Attribute("cnumber").Value,
                        Verse = verse
                    })
                    .Select(x => new
                    {
                        Translation = bibleName,
                        Reference = $"{x.BookName} {x.ChapterNumber}:{x.Verse.Attribute("vnumber").Value}",
                        Scripture = x.Verse.Value
                    });

                    return fetchBible.ToList();
                });
                
                
                dgvScriptures.DataSource = loadBible;
                dgvScriptures.Columns[1].Width = 200;
                dgvScriptures.Columns[2].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
```

Comment: The `Task.Run` method offloads work to the `ThreadPool`. Accessing UI elements (like the `DataGridViewRow`) is supposed to happen only from the UI thread, so the whole idea of using `Task.Run` here is flawed. You could configure the property `Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = true` at the start of your WinForms application (only in DEBUG mode), in order to catch up such mistakes earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Why you use TextChanged ?

What about KeyPress Enter or TextBox Leave event?

Should you search in real time?

I think error accoured because of

```
.Where(r => r.Cells[1].Value.ToString().Contains(txtSearchReference.Text))
```

this line

Becuase You are using Async, while linq is finding, txtSearchReference.Text < is changed.

so nothing is founded and 'DataGridViewRow row' will be null

Then What about using DataGridView Filter?

try this one
[Filtering DataGridView without changing datasource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843537/filtering-datagridview-without-changing-datasource)

Comment: Yes, i want to search realtime

Comment: Yes, the exception error comes from that line of code, could you help me fix it?

Comment: And also I have 3000+ data to read, how can I the system read it fast when searching in datagridview

Comment: I have edited my question, i posted my code how I loaded my XML database in datagridview. hope it helps to understand my concern.