# Invert SQL Query to find

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2019

hopefully someone can give me some pointers here. I haven't worked with SQL or VB for quite a long time now.
Recently I had been asked if I can make a Windows Application that does some searching through a SQL database and returns everything between the given times. The database is a simple one that contains about 14 columns and is for flights from different airports. Right now I have the code pulling all data from two departure dates and two arrival dates.

Right now everything seems to be working as expected, but the issue that I have is figuring out how to filter the Grid View so that it is only showing the filtered objects. I saw something about adding Excel like filters to the columns which would be ideal for me, but I cannot seem to get that to work. The other option is if I have some textboxes to use as a filter. But I have NO idea how to do that, especially since they may include multiple bits of criteria.

So right now the way it looks is this:[image]

But as you can see there are filter boxes along the left side that I am not sure how to make it work. Currently the code that I have for the button select is:

```
Dim conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=sqlserver;Initial Catalog=Flight_Records;Integrated Security=True")
        conn.Open()
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(" 
                                    SELECT *
                                    FROM dbo.FAA_RR
                                    WHERE 
                                    (Departure_DATETIME_UTC between @DEP_Date1 and @DEP_Date2
                                    OR Arrival_DATETIME_UTC between @ARR_Date1 and @ARR_Date2)                       
                                  ", conn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("DEP_Date1", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DEP_Date1.Value
        cmd.Parameters.Add("DEP_Date2", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DEP_Date2.Value
        cmd.Parameters.Add("ARR_Date1", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = ARR_Date1.Value
        cmd.Parameters.Add("ARR_Date2", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = ARR_Date2.Value

        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        dt.Clear()
        da.Fill(dt)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
        conn.Close()
```

I tried doing this, but it didn't work(obviously!):

```
        Dim conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=sqlserver;Initial Catalog=Flight_Records;Integrated Security=True")
        conn.Open()
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(" 
                                    SELECT *
                                    FROM dbo.FAA_RR
                                    WHERE 
                                    '****ADDED THIS****
                                    Aircraft_ID = @AircraftID 
                                    (Departure_DATETIME_UTC between @DEP_Date1 and @DEP_Date2
                                    OR Arrival_DATETIME_UTC between @ARR_Date1 and @ARR_Date2)                       
                                    
                                  ", conn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("DEP_Date1", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DEP_Date1.Value
        cmd.Parameters.Add("DEP_Date2", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DEP_Date2.Value
        cmd.Parameters.Add("ARR_Date1", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = ARR_Date1.Value
        cmd.Parameters.Add("ARR_Date2", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = ARR_Date2.Value

        '****ADDED THIS****
        If tbAircraftID.Text = "" Then cmd.Parameters.Add("AircraftID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "Aircraft_ID" Else cmd.Parameters.Add("AircraftID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = tbAircraftID.Text

        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        dt.Clear()
        da.Fill(dt)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
        conn.Close()
```

Again, I am no coder, I only know enough to just do simple things with the exception of powershell.
Does anyone have any clue where I should start? Especially since they may want to add several different things like multiple 'Departure Airports' like: "SEA,OAK,PDX"

I would actually prefer if there was a way to sort and filter like in Excel. I saw something about DataGridViewAutoFilter, but everything seems to be for C# and I have no idea how to include that. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Most TextBoxes should be ComboBoxes (except `Unique Flight ID`), so you can select predefined elements (as the Airport ID). `Aircraft ID` should also probably be a selector, since its DataSource can be the `Aircraft_ID` Column. -- If no selection is made, you don't filter that Column (so, add a first line in the ComboBoxes that means <`Any>`).

Comment: Check : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843537/filtering-datagridview-without-changing-datasource/ . You can convert the code to VB.

Comment: Thank You all for your assistance. I figured out the best way for me was to add the excel like filtering by adding AdvancedDataGridView by adding it from the NuGet package.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use query in vb codes, you must use this codes in where clause:

```
WHERE Aircraft_id like textbox1.text & '% AND ' &
 UniqueFlightId like textbox2.text & '%'
```

If you can use stored procedure

```
create procedure SP_test (@Aircraft_id nvarchar(50))

AS

select ....
from ...
WHERE Aircraft_id like @Aircraft_id  & '% AND ' ....
```